# How do I write tickets to Zendesk API using POST JSON requests in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, zendesk, zendesk-app

Note: I have posted this on Mr. Excel as well.  Link [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-do-i-write-tickets-to-zendesk-api-using-post-json-requests-in-vba.1124009/).

I am trying to write a ticket to a Zendesk API from Access/Excel using VBA.  I keep receiving the following error:

"error":"Unprocessable Entity","message":"server could not parse JSON"

My code is as follows: (replacing my actual Zendesk domain, username, and token with "zendeskdomain", "username", and "token" respectively).

```
 Dim strURL As String, strParse() As String, jsonStr As String
 Dim hreq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
 Dim tixScript As Object

 strURL = "https://zendeskdomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json"
 hreq.Open "POST", strURL, 0, "username/token", "token"

 hreq.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Chrome/78.0.3904.108"
 hreq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
 hreq.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"

 jsonStr = """{""ticket"": {""subject"": ""Testing post requests"", ""requester_id"":393329203772, ""comment"": { ""body"": ""This will work"" }}}"""

 hreq.Send jsonStr

 MsgBox hreq.responseText
```

I was able to take the same JSON string and create a ticket using the actual Zendesk Developer API.  I was also able to make a GET connection to work using the same three request headers used in the POST code above.

I feel like I am missing something simple, but I cannot seem to make it work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The outer pairs of double quotes are unnecessary and make `jsonStr` contain invalid JSON. Using `Debug.Print` in VBA shows that `jsonStr` ends up containing:

```
"{"ticket": {"subject": "Testing post requests", "requester_id":393329203772, "comment": { "body": "This will work" }}}"
```

Change the line that sets `jsonStr` to:

```
jsonStr = "{""ticket"": {""subject"": ""Testing post requests"", ""requester_id"":393329203772, ""comment"": { ""body"": ""This will work"" }}}"
```